# Storing 2 different arrays in local Storage js

Tags: javascript, storage, local

For example, I have 2 arrays. One is myFavCars and one is myDislikedCars.
How can I store them in local storage something like:

```
localStorage.setItem('myPreferences', { myFavCars: [], myDislikedCars: [] })
```

Is possible to store 2 different arrays in one item on local storage?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can with `JSON.stringify` to parse it to string, but then you will get a `string` you need to parse it back to `Object`.

```
localStorage.setItem('myPreferences',JSON.stringify({ myFavCars: [], myDislikedCars: []}))
```

And can read it with this:

```
const objt = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myPreferences'))
```

Comment: yeah, but my problem is that 2 arrays are updating so when I fav a new car I should set in local storage, but this:
`localStorage.setItem('myPreferences',JSON.stringify({ myFavCars: [favCarsLocalArray] }))`
will replace the viewed one :(